# Specifying a custom Window's default appearance in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, window, styles

I would like to make a library of some of my commonly used WPF controls, and one of these controls is a `CustomWindow` which inherits from the `Window` class. How can I get my `CustomWindow` to use a default appearance that is defined in the library with it?

I can replace

```
<Window x:Class="..." />
```

with

```
<MyControls:CustomWindow x:Class="..." />
```

and it works for the window behavior, but not the appearnce.

**EDIT**

Here is a simplified version of what I have so far:

Custom Window Control. Located in the Control library.

```
public class CustomChromeWindow: Window
{
    static CustomChromeWindow()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomChromeWindow), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomChromeWindow)));
    } 
}
```

Window Style. Located in a Generic.xaml, a ResourceDictionary in the Themes folder of the control library

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomChromeWindow">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Test Window. Startup window of a separate project that references the control library

```
<local:CustomChromeWindow
    x:Class="MyControlsTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyControls;assembly=MyControls"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="This is a Test" />
    </Grid>
</local:CustomChromeWindow>
```

What I end up getting is a window with the regular WindowStyle and a black background.

Comment: What do you mean by "appearance"? Are you setting properties? Adding child elements?

Comment: @Joe White: Both. I am setting some properties such as WindowStyle, Background, MaxHeight, etc and also overwritting the template. The new template has it's own Titlebar, min/max/close buttons, round menu button, etc.

Comment: mdm20's answer worked for me. I had something similar and I moved the file to a different project. VS2012 doesn't copy the ThemeInfo statement to the new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.CustomWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MyControls="MyNamespace">

    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MyControls:CustomWindow">
        ...
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>

    <ContentPresenter />

</Window>
```

You may want to design a new theme for the window. If so place following theme in (your library)\Themes\Generic.xaml resource file:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:CustomWindow}">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
    ...

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:CustomWindow}">
                <Border>
                    ...
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: When overriding window theme you must design a completely new template.
Use first xaml if you want to keep default template, and use second one to completely replace it.

Comment: The whole point of putting the Window in another library is to avoid having to rewrite the window template in every application that uses the window. I am trying to get it working now with the Generic.xaml file but not having much luck with that.

Comment: Note that a window that has xaml cann't be the root of another window. So you can't for example change it's style in xaml. Designing a new template for the window allows to inherit from base window and change it's properties in xaml.

Comment: You are correct. To create a custom Window Template, I need to completely re-create the window object, including things like resizing and min/max/close buttons. If I were simply re-styling it things would be much easier, but I want to change the template too.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the AssemblyInfo.cs file in your class library

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (put this in the default Cctor) :

```
 DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomWindow)
                                             , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomWindow)));`
```

Comment: That does something, but not what it's supposed to do. I specified `WindowStyle=None` and `Background=Red` to test, and instead I get the regular window style but with a black background.

Comment: hmm, can u post quick XAML mockup of your problem?

Comment: how are u loading your Generic.xaml Resource dictionary (which has the style)?